# CoreOS Image fails to load ignition file via libvirt (permission denied)

Tags: qemu, coreos, libvirt, fedora-coreos

I'm testing out a new network config using VM's and got libvirt and qemu setup on my system. Following the documentation for Fedora CoreOS to help get started.

**Steps Taken**

- I've updated my user to be a member of **kvm** and **libvirt** groups

  ```
  > groups
  [ .. ] video kvm fuse libvirt
  ```
- Created Ignition YAML and exported to the JSON .ign file

  ```
  {"ignition":{"version":"3.1.0"},"passwd":{"users":[{ ...
  ```
- Running the kvm command directly using the documentation works as expected. I am able to ssh into the system
- libvirt is able to generate an XML using the steps in the original CoreOS Documentation (https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-with-libvirt.html#virtual-machine-startup) with the qemu commands attached

  ```xml
  ...
  <qemu:commandline xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0">
    <qemu:arg value="-fw_cfg"/>
    <qemu:arg value="name=opt/com.coreos/config,file=/var/lib/libvirt/machine/main.ign"/>
  </qemu:commandline>
  ```
- Tried setting ignition file's permissions to "kvm" and "libvirt" with no change. Currently all files using libvirt:

  ```
  $ ls -l /var/lib/libvirt/machine/
  total 8
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root libvirt 2242 Sep 20 17:16 domain.xml
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root libvirt  658 Sep 20 17:15 main.ign
  ```
- Machine is loaded and displayed in virt-manager

  ```
  $ virsh list --all
  Id   Name      State
  -----------------------------
  -    machine   shut off
  ```

Only issue is the machine will not work from virt-manager or virsh:

```
$ virsh start machine
error: Failed to start domain machine
error: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2020-09-21T00:34:59.972390Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]
2020-09-21T00:34:59.972427Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
2020-09-21T00:34:59.973278Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]
2020-09-21T00:34:59.973287Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
2020-09-21T00:34:59.980931Z qemu-system-x86_64: -fw_cfg name=opt/com.coreos/config,file=/var/lib/libvirt/machine/main.ign: can't load /var/lib/libvirt/machine/main.ign: Failed to open file “/var/lib/libvirt/machine/main.ign”: Permission denied
```

Now out of ideas on what to do. Someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the following line in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`

```
security_driver = "none"
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting

```
security_driver = "none"
```

in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf and restart libvirtd worked for me to solve a similar problem. (Debian 11, neither AppArmor or SELinux activated / used at all). Error here looked like:

```
Error: error creating libvirt domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: ...
```

and

```
Could not open '/var/lib/libvirt/images/d1test4-centos7.qcow2': Permission denied
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
# mv main.ign /var/lib/libvirt/images/
# restorecon /var/lib/libvirt/images/main.ign
```

`/var/lib/libvirt/images` is properly permissioned and selinux labelled for VMs to access. `/var/lib/libvirt/machines` is not a standard libvirt directory so depending on how you created it the qemu process may not have access. Also on Fedora the qemu process is launched as 'qemu' user, not 'kvm' or 'libvirt', so it could be due to that too, but if the file is in /var/lib/libvirt/images and global read permissions then I think that should be enough

Comment: I'm using a Debian based distro for the Host OS, not Fedora so I don't think SELinux is a factor.

Comment: I did notice there's a separate libvirt-qemu user/group and a /var/lib/libvirt/qemu directory with libvirt-qemu:kvm owner. I tried copying the ignition file to that directory, set the permission to the same owner and re-define the machine domain. Still getting Permission Denied.

Comment: Hmm not sure then. I know ubuntu enables apparmor by default but I don't know how to turn that off besides disabling it for all of libvirt in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`. I would try putting the file in /tmp and change permissions to 777. If you can get that to work, start dialing bits back to find the culprit: does dropping write permission still work, does putting in a /tmp subdir work, things like that.

Comment: Great idea. Checked qemu.conf and it appears to be disabled but set to SELinux by default. Didn't think there was anything there to change. Also checked AppArmor to see what would be affected `apparmor_status | grep libvirtd` gave: 
`libvirtd, libvirtd//qemu_bridge_helper, /usr/sbin/libvirtd (1359) libvirtd` (formatted)
Also tried placing a copy of the ign file in /tmp with full file permissions, no change.

Comment: Is there a way to turn off apparmor temporarily? If even /tmp + full permissions doesn't work the only thing I can think is that it's selinux or apparmor. libvirt and selinux/apparmor coordinate to make sure all files referenced in the XML are properly labelled... except when using qemu command line passthrough which is opaque to libvirt, so the files won't get proper label.